# fopen(/home/loyusgyp/public_html/logs/log_jurosemulta/log_2020-02-02_18-00-01.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in (Cpanel)

Tags: php, log, fopen

Pessoal estou com problema na hora de gravar um log no meu servidor de hospedagem(hospedagem utiliza o cpanel).
Criei um job de correção de juros e multa, porém quando o job roda ele acusa o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: fopen(/home/loyusgyp/public_html/logs/log_jurosemulta/log_2020-02-02_18-00-01.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/loyusgyp/public_html/job/job-correcao-valor.php on line 77
```

O mais engraçado é que se eu acessar o caminho pela url é executar manualmente, o mesmo efetua tudo que precisa e por fim grava o log na hospedagem. Exemplo:

```
http://localhost/job/job-correcao-valor.php
```

Segue o meu codigo:

**function correcaoJursoEMulta();**

```
include_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../db/db_connect.php"));

date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
$date_sem_horas = date("Y-m-d");
$date_com_horas = date("Y-m-d_H-i-s");

$titulos_em_vencimento = "SELECT pag.COD_PAGAMENTO,pag.DATA_VENCIMENTO,pag.VALOR,pla.VALOR_PLANO,alu.NOM_ALUNO,pag.DAT_OPERACAO 
                            FROM contrato con
                            inner join aluno alu        on alu.COD_ALUNO = con.COD_ALUNO
                            INNER JOIN pagamento  pag   on pag.COD_ALUNO = alu.COD_ALUNO        
                            inner join planos pla       on pla.COD_PLANO = con.COD_PLANO
                            WHERE pag.DATA_VENCIMENTO < now() 
                            AND pag.TIPO_PAGAMENTO = 'Mensalidade' 
                            AND pag.STATUS = 'Aberto'";
$resultado_titulos_em_vencimento = mysqli_query($connect, $titulos_em_vencimento) or die (mysqli_error($connect));


while($titulos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_titulos_em_vencimento))
{
    $cod_titulo = $titulos['COD_PAGAMENTO'];
    $data_titulos = $titulos['DATA_VENCIMENTO'];
    $nom_aluno = $titulos['NOM_ALUNO'];
    $valor_plano = $titulos['VALOR_PLANO'];
    $data_operacao = $titulos['DAT_OPERACAO'];

    if($data_operacao == $date_sem_horas){
        $msg = "Titulo já corrigido | Aluno: $nom_aluno | Data da operação: $date_sem_horas\n";
        logMe($msg,$date_com_horas);
    }else{
        $valor_corrigido = calcular($date_sem_horas,$data_titulos,$valor_plano);
        atualizarValor($valor_corrigido,$cod_titulo,$date_sem_horas,$nom_aluno,$date_com_horas);
    }
}
```

**function calcular($date_sem_horas,$data_titulos,$valor_plano)**

```
$diferenca = strtotime($date_sem_horas) - strtotime($data_titulos);
    $dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));

    $data1 = new DateTime( $date_sem_horas );
    $data2 = new DateTime( $data_titulos );

    $intervalo = $data1->diff($data2);
    $converterIntervaloNumero = intval($intervalo->m + 1);

    $multa = number_format(4.50, 2, '.', '');
    $multaFinal = $multa * $converterIntervaloNumero;
    $juros = $valor_plano * 0.003;
    $totalJuros = $juros * $dias;
    $calculoFinal = number_format($totalJuros + $multaFinal + $valor_plano, 2, '.', '');

    return $calculoFinal;
```

**function atualizarValor($valor_corrigido,$cod_titulo,$date_sem_horas,$nom_aluno,$date_com_horas)**

```
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../db/db_connect.php"));

$atualizar_titulo = "UPDATE pagamento set VALOR = '$valor_corrigido', DAT_OPERACAO = '$date_sem_horas' WHERE COD_PAGAMENTO = '$cod_titulo'";
$resultado_atualizar_titulo = mysqli_query($connect, $atualizar_titulo) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect)){
    $msg = "Juros e multa corrigido | Aluno: $nom_aluno | Valor: $valor_corrigido | Data da operação: $date_sem_horas\n";
    logMe($msg,$date_com_horas);
}
```

**function logMe($msg,$date_com_horas)**

```
$fp = fopen("../logs/log_jurosemulta/log_".$date_com_horas.".txt", "a");
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` é sobre a localização a seguir não existir:

> ../logs/log_jurosemulta

O problema **NÃO tem nada haver com o modo de abertura do `fopen` ("a significa "append"")**.

Só pra constar, é "pouco provável" que este erro seja sobre permissão de pastas, pois quando você tem falha de permissão o PHP emite o seguinte erro:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

Os problemas podem ser:

- A pasta `logs` não existe ou tem outro nome
- A pasta `log_jurosemulta` não existe ou tem outro nome
- Seu servidor é Linux e suas pastas tem nomes com letras maiúsculas, mas você escreveu tudo em minúsculo, lembre-se Linux é case-sensitive para arquivos e pastas
- O `..` está em um caminho relativo e partir do script que vou invocado está caindo em um caminho absoluto (internamente no PHP) diferente

No caso do ultimo item, que creio ser o mais provável do seu caso, para saber para aonde o `fopen` está apontando faça isto (apenas para depurar, remova do script depois):

```
function logMe($msg,$date_com_horas) {

var_dump(realpath("../logs/log_jurosemulta"));
var_dump(getcwd());

$fp = fopen("../logs/log_jurosemulta/log_".$date_com_horas.".txt", "a");
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
}
```

O `realpath` vai exibir o possível caminho real da pasta, se retornar `false` é porque dê fato está apontando para o caminho errado, neste caso para facilitar seria melhor usar o caminho absoluto, porque **caminhos relativos** dependem do caminho atual de execução do script atual (que pode ser obtido com [**`getcwd()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)).

Se essa "depuração" com `var_dump` retornar um caminho possível então verifique se é de fato o caminho correto.

Note que você pode usar o `__DIR__`, mas antes de usar tem que tomar cuidado e entender ele, o `__DIR__` indica pasta do script que está incluído, então supondo (**é hipotético**) que sua estrutura esta assim:

```
./public_html
  ├───index.php
  ├───libs
  │   ├───conexao.php
  │   └───funcoes.php
  │
  └───logs
      └───log_jurosemulta
```

E supondo que sua função `function logMe` está no arquivo `funcoes.php` o script deveria ficar assim:

```
function logMe($msg,$date_com_horas) {
    $fp = fopen(__DIR__ . "/../logs/log_jurosemulta/log_".$date_com_horas.".txt", "a");
    $escreve = fwrite($fp, $msg);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Neste caso o `__DIR__` teria o seguinte valor:

> ./public_html/libs

Então concatenando com `/../logs/log_jurosemulta/*`, ele sobe um nivel, indo para `public_html` e a partir disto acessando a pasta aonde deve estar os logs, mas note, isto tudo é para explicar, imagino que você deva ter uma estrutura diferente, então basta entender os níveis das pastas, não bastar copiar e colar o código, tem que ajustar ao que você tem.

Answer (score 0):

[Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433875/172323) está correta ao afirmar que o problema está no path para o seu arquivo. Entretanto, gostaria de apontar uma alternativa, para não ser necessário verificar todos os usos de path relativos.

Considerando os pontos

> Criei um job de correção de juros e multa, porém quando o job roda ele acusa o seguinte erro

e

> se eu acessar o caminho pela url é executar manualmente

é possível inferir que o problema não está no script, mas sim no setup do cron job. *(Inclusive era melhor ter deixado isso mais explícito e incluir o setup do cron à pergunta.)*

Para corrigir o problema **ao correr o script via cron**, é preciso alterar o seu cron.

Imagino que algo como `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/loyusgyp/public_html/job/job-correcao-valor.php` tenha sido feito, sendo que o path para o executável do PHP, quanto o agendamento podem ser diferentes.

Neste caso, é preciso alterar o comando que é executado no CRON para `cd /home/loyusgyp/public_html && /usr/bin/php ./job/job-correcao-valor.php` e o script será executado a partir de `/home/loyusgyp/public_html` e, consequentemente, tentará escrever os logs em `/home/loyusgyp/logs/log_jurosemulta/`.

Comment: *"Não aponta a devida correção"*, como assim? Ele nem mesmo apresentou como executou o script, independente de como foi eu respondi a isso sim, eu disse bem claro em *"porque caminhos relativos dependem do caminho atual de execução do script atual (que pode ser obtido com getcwd())."*, ou seja ele usou `../` que é relativo, se o script é acessivel via HTTP e ao mesmo tempo pelo CRON então `__DIR__` resolve perfeitamente sempre precisar ser explicito em nada, porque o `__DIR__` já é o "explicito" (ou quase, depende do que vier depois).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, está melhor agora?