# Cron com problemas para executar arquivo PHP

Tags: php, linux, cron

Estou com um problema ao executar minhas tarefas no Cron.

Quando eu acesso o script a ser executado pelo navegador ele funciona normalmente, porém quando ele é executado pelo cron, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(../../Config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sitebr/public_html/Model/Routines/Pattern.php on line 8
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../Config.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/sitebr/public_html/Model/Routines/Pattern.php on line 8
```

Sou iniciante com o Cron, então talvez seja algo simples que eu não saiba como funciona.

Agora explicando melhor a parte dos arquivos, eu tenho uma estrutura de pastas mais ou menos assim:

```
|-public_html
  |-Model
    |-Routines
      |-Pattern.php
      |-Rotina1.php
      |-Rotina2.php
      |-Rotina3.php
  |-Controller
    |-AutoLoad.php
  |-Config.php
```

Todas as rotinas fazem um `require_once` no arquivo `Pattern.php` que contem configurações padrão que serão importantes por todas elas, segue conteudo do arquivo `Pattern.php`:

```
<?php
  error_reporting (E_ALL);
  ini_set ("log_errors","1");
  ini_set ("error_log",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ErroSistem.txt");
  ini_set ("display_errors" ,"0");
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);

  require_once("../../Config.php");
  require_once("../../Controller/AutoLoad.php");
```

O problema está nesses dois `require_once` dentro do `Pattern.php`, ele não consegue encontrar os arquivos, mas seguindo a estrutura de pastas ele está ok e testando via navegador também está ok.

O `require_once` que tem dentro das rotinas, chamando o arquivo `Pattern.php` funciona bem, não apresenta nenhum erro mesmo pelo Cron.

As rotinas foram configuradas pelo cPanel, na interfacce gráfica, usando o comando:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/sitebr/public_html/Model/Routines/Rotina1.php
```

Alguém tem uma ideia do que seja?

Comment: Faça isso só pra checar se funciona `require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../Config.php");`, o `__DIR__` vai pegar a partir do caminho do script que é executado, mesmo que ele esteja incluido, se executar direto ../ ele vai pegar a partir do script chamado e não do "incluido" (acaso a chamada ../ seja dentro do incluido).

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [fopen(/home/loyusgyp/public\_html/logs/log\_jurosemulta/log\_2020-02-02\_18-00-01.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in (Cpanel)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433849/fopen-home-loyusgyp-public-html-logs-log-jurosemulta-log-2020-02-02-18-00-01-tx)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento consegui resolver com o __DIR__, foquei tanto no cron e deixei passar o básico do php kkkk fiz essa alteração e mais umas no Autoload e tudo funcionando agora, obrigado.

Comment: @tvdias responde sim, não tinha conseguido achar esse post antes, mas apesar de eu ter resolvido com a dica do amigo acima, o post ajudou também.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria alterar o comando do CRON para `cd /home/sitebr/public_html/ && /usr/local/bin/php ./Model/Routines/Rotina1.php`

Com isso, o "local de execução do script" é alterado para ser o mesmo utilizado pelo web server: `/home/sitebr/public_html/`.

Comment: Lembrando que seria mais útil se as pessoas que votam contra deixassem um comentário. Assim, não somente o AR, como também o AP poderia saber o que há de errado.